# Static structure, dynamic behaviour - do these apply?

Tags: tapestry

I know there are a few of this kind of questions around, but I don't think they answer my question.

I would like to allow Admin user of my application to change the components and their order on specific pages. So eg:

Page A will have Components 1, 2, 3
Page B will have Components 4, 3, 2

I am not trying to modify it after the page is load, but before (the required structure for the page could for example be read from database).

Does this violates the static structure of Tapestry? Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this using Blocks and the Delegate component.

Obviously you will need to work on the logic of the `get...Block` methods, but you should be able to figure something out.

The static structure in this case, refers to the fact that your markup needs to declare all of the embedded components that *might* be rendered. You can then use logic and other components to decide what gets rendered in which order.

java:

```
public class MyPage
{
    @Inject
    public Block block1;
    @Inject
    public Block block2;
    @Inject
    public Block block3;
    @Inject
    public Block block4;

    public Block getFirstBlock()
    {
        return caseA ? block1 : block4;
    }

    public Block getSecondBlock()
    {
        return caseA ? block2 : block3;
    }

    public Block getThirdBlock()
    {
        return caseA ? block3 : block2;
    }
}
```

tml:

```
<...>
    <t:block t:id="block1"><t:component1 /></t:block>
    <t:block t:id="block2"><t:component2 /></t:block>
    <t:block t:id="block3"><t:component3 /></t:block>
    <t:block t:id="block4"><t:component4 /></t:block>

    <t:delegate to="firstBlock" />
    <t:delegate to="secondBlock" />
    <t:delegate to="thirdBlock" />
</...>
```